# Await doesn't give a result

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous, networking, async-await

Ok, I have some code to present. Here is extension method for `NetworkStream` object.

```
public async static Task<byte[]> ReadDataAsync(this NetworkStream clientStream)
{
    byte[] data = {};

    var buffer = new byte[1024];
    if (clientStream.CanRead)
    {
        using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            try
            {
                int bytesRead;
                while (clientStream.DataAvailable && 
                  (bytesRead = await clientStream.ReadAsync(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
                {
                    await ms.WriteAsync(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
                return data;
            }

            data = ms.ToArray();
        }
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Closing clientStream.");
        clientStream.Close();
    }
    return data;
}
```

And the code where I am trying to call this method.

```
public async static Task Preform(Socket client)
{
    var stream = new NetworkStream(client);
    var data = await stream.ReadDataAsync();
    var message = await MessageFabrique.DeserializeMessage(data);

    ServerCollections.Instance.ServerIssueQueue.Add(new ServerIssue
    {
        Message = message,
        ClientStream = stream
    });
}
```

`ReadDataAsync` method always returns me to an empty array. And at the moment when i'm trying to deserialize data there is an exception - because `data[0]`. Please help me. Why is this happening, if `await` *guarantees* me the result, when it needed?

Comment: Are you sure you're not getting and exception in your catch block? It will return data[0].

Comment: Are you running in a console application?

Comment: @Sergey.quixoticaxis.Ivanov, No. I didn't catch exceptions in this area.

Comment: @EJoshuaS, Yeap... but what's wrong with it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`clientStream.DataAvailable` does not mean data might show up in the future. It means data is available right now for reading. Get rid of it and just read, the read will block till data shows up or will return 0 when the stream hits it's end.

Comment: Thnx, Scot. I'll try it.

Answer (score 0):

Scott's answer is right, but .Net already takes care of you...

You might consider [`Stream.CopyToAsync`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh159084(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
await clientStream.CopyToAsync(ms)
```

for code with considerably less places to go wrong.

Comment: Can I doing it without using a loop, 'while' at this case?

Comment: @TrumanStarr, yes, `CopyToAsync` will copy *all* of a stream to another one in a single operation.

Comment: danke for hint!

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the other answers, you might also want to create a synchronization context. See [this article](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/pfxteam/2012/01/20/await-synchronizationcontext-and-console-apps/) for details.

The summary is that async/await works differently in console applications than it does in a UI application. WPF and WebForms applications have a synchronization context by default but console applications don't. The result (which is actually remarkably "poorly advertised" in the documentation) is that the behavior of async/await is *much* less predictable in a console application than it is in a UI application, and that this might make it not work "as advertised" under certain circumstances.

For example, in a UI application "async" doesn't necessarily mean that the code runs on a background thread. It's the equivalent of "come back to me later when I'm ready." As an analogy, consider going out to eat with 10 people: when the waiter comes by, the first person he asks to order isn't ready. Two bad solutions here would be to a) bring in a second waiter to either wait for the first guy to become ready or take the other 9 people's orders) or b) wait until the first guy's ready to start taking orders. The optimal thing is to take the other 9 people's orders and then come back to the first guy hoping he'll be ready by that time. At risk of oversimplifying this is basically how async works in a UI (unless you're explicitly putting the code on a background thread with something like Task.Run). However, in a console application when you use async there's no guarantee as to where the code will actually run.

If, however, you add a synchronization context as described in the the article I link to it'll behave in a much more predictable manner.

Comment: I start ever communication server-client over callback to `Task.Run(() => ...).ConfigureAwait(false)`. I think i's matter in this case. Thanx.

Comment: @TrumanStarr There's not necessarily a clear performance benefit to putting it on a background thread if all you're doing is waiting for a result.